# Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'presentedat' untranslated

Tags: biblatex, biber, babel, spanish

Biber + babel doesn't translate `presentedat` in `@inproceedings` causing bad output in references.

I think the problem is because using `@inproceedings` but that was automatically generated by Zotero. Should I change the type of reference? To what?

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@inproceedings{davenport_thermal_2022,
    location = {Freiburg, Germany},
    title = {Thermal stability of silica for application in thermal energy storage},
    url = {https://pubs.aip.org/aip/acp/article/2824318},
    doi = {10.1063/5.0085641},
    eventtitle = {{SOLARPACES} 2020: 26th International Conference on Concentrating Solar Power and Chemical Energy Systems},
    pages = {160003},
    author = {Davenport, Patrick and Ma, Zhiwen and Nation, William and Schirck, Jason and Morris, Aaron and Lambert, Matthew},
    urldate = {2023-05-18},
    date = {2022},
    langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Is this a typography mistake?** `presentdate` written as `presentedat`

## EDIT

---

I have changed `@inproceedings` to `@incollection`

[image]

That solved my problem, but... how to do the same when keeping `@inproceedings` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bold text in `biblatex`-generated output usually means something is missing or otherwise went wrong. And indeed looking at the `.log` output of your MWE we find

```
Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'presentedat' untranslated
(biblatex)                at entry 'davenport_thermal_2022' on input line 31.
```

Since your document language is Spanish that means that `biblatex` cannot find a Spanish translation of the bibstring `presentedat` that is used by `biblatex-ieee` in front of the conference name for `@inproceedings`.

You probably want to give a Spanish translation for the English "presented at the ..." string

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{
  presentedat = presented at the\addspace,
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{davenport_thermal_2022,
  location   = {Freiburg, Germany},
  title      = {Thermal Stability of Silica for Application in Thermal Energy Storage},
  url        = {https://pubs.aip.org/aip/acp/article/2824318},
  doi        = {10.1063/5.0085641},
  eventtitle = {{SOLARPACES} 2020: 26th International Conference
                on Concentrating Solar Power and Chemical Energy Systems},
  pages      = {160003},
  author     = {Davenport, Patrick and Ma, Zhiwen and Nation, William
                and Schirck, Jason and Morris, Aaron and Lambert, Matthew},
  urldate    = {2023-05-18},
  date       = {2022},
  langid     = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: P. Davenport, Z. Ma, W. Nation, J. Schirck, A. Morris y M. Lambert, <<Thermal stability of silica for application in thermal energy storage,>> presented at the SOLARPACES 2020: 26th International Conference on Concentrating Solar Power and Chemical Energy Systems, Freiburg, Germany, 2022, pág. 160003. doi: 10.1063/5.0085641. dirección: https://pubs.aip.org/aip/acp/article/2824318 (visitado 18-05-2023).]

If you don't like this introductory string at all you can remove it for good with

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{%
  \printfield{eventtitle}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{venue}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{eventyear}}
  }
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{venue}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
       \printeventdate}}%
  \newunit
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{davenport_thermal_2022,
  location   = {Freiburg, Germany},
  title      = {Thermal Stability of Silica for Application in Thermal Energy Storage},
  url        = {https://pubs.aip.org/aip/acp/article/2824318},
  doi        = {10.1063/5.0085641},
  eventtitle = {{SOLARPACES} 2020: 26th International Conference
                on Concentrating Solar Power and Chemical Energy Systems},
  pages      = {160003},
  author     = {Davenport, Patrick and Ma, Zhiwen and Nation, William
                and Schirck, Jason and Morris, Aaron and Lambert, Matthew},
  urldate    = {2023-05-18},
  date       = {2022},
  langid     = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```